# How to store high quality image in iphone Library?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, resolution

I have taken 1 high quality image and stored it to some place

```
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
 NSArray *docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);
 NSString *docDir = [docDirs objectAtIndex:0];
 BOOL success = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test11.png"] atomically:YES];
```

I can see from xcode organizer the **image resolution is very high quality**.
**Dimension: 2592 × 1936 ... size 6.1MB**

My problem is how can I **store high quality image in iphone Library**. I am **strictly not allowed to store compressed image**. I have to **store only HD high quality image.**

Please do not reply with scaleAndRotateImage functions because it will compress image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALAssetsLibrary class will let you do that.

Comment: Thanks I have used the same :)